# How can I display descriptive statistics next to each other by using stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

My dataset has a dummy variable which divides the data set into two groups. I would like to display the descriptive statistics for both next to each other, like:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLDzZ.png)

using stargazer. Is this possible?

For example, if there is the mtcars data set and the variable $am divides the dataset into two groups, how can I display the one group on the left side and the other group on the other side?

Thank you!

I was able to display the two statistics below each other (I had to make two separate datasets for each group), but never next to each other.

```
treated <- mtcars[mtcars$am == 1,]
control <- mtcars[mtcars$am == 0,]

stargazer(treated, control, keep=c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"), 
          header=FALSE, title="Descriptive statistics", digits=1, type="text")
```

[Descriptive statistics below each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXcbn.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing your data (or example data) to go with your code?

Comment: I have edited my post and added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone should point out if I'm mistaken, but I don't believe that `stargazer` will allow for the kind of nested tables you are looking for. However, there are other packages like `modelsummary`, `gtsummary`, and `flextable` that can produce tables similar to `stargazer`. I have included examples below using select `mtcars` variables summarized by `am`. Personally, I prefer `gtsummary` due to its flexibility.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

### modelsummary
# not great since it treats `cyl` as a continuous variable
# https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html
library(modelsummary)
datasummary_balance(~am, data = mtcars, dinm = FALSE)

### gtsummary
# based on example 3 from here
# https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_stat_label.html
library(gtsummary)
mtcars %>%
  select(am, mpg, cyl, disp, hp) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = am, 
    missing = "no",
    type = list(mpg ~ 'continuous2',
                cyl ~ 'categorical',
                disp ~ 'continuous2',
                hp ~ 'continuous2'),
    statistic = all_continuous2() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})", "{median}")
    ) %>%
  add_stat_label(label = c(mpg, disp, hp) ~ c("Mean (SD)", "Median")) %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA)

### flextable
# this function only works on continuous vars, so I removed `cyl`
# https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/continuous_summary.html
library(flextable)
mtcars %>%
  select(am, mpg, cyl, disp, hp) %>%
  continuous_summary(
    by = "am",
    hide_grouplabel = FALSE,
    digits = 3
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `modelsummary` package and its `datasummary` function, which offers a formula-based language to describe the specific table you need. (Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.)

In addition to the super flexible `datasummary` function, there are many other functions to summarize data in easier ways. See in particular the `datasummary_balance()` function here:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html

```r
library(modelsummary)
dat <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "am")]
datasummary(
    All(dat) ~ Factor(am) * (N + Mean + SD + Min + Max),
    data = dat)
```

[image]